# TypeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I have recently had a problem with the date conversion function.

The code itself works with the Telegram Core API and should receive messages from the channels I need. The function itself seems to work fine, except for the part of the code where the date and time are serialized, this error occurs in it:

```
Unhandled exception on list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 467, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "E:\freelance\bot_admin\launch2.py", line 83, in list
    await dump_all_messages( channel )
  File "E:\freelance\bot_admin\launch2.py", line 74, in dump_all_messages
    json.dump(all_messages, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 429, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 439, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "E:\freelance\bot_admin\launch2.py", line 49, in default
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
  File "C:\Users\79607\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable
```

And here is all the code I have at this moment:

```
import configparser
import json
import datetime

from telethon.sync import TelegramClient , events
from telethon import connection


from datetime import date, datetime


from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch


from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetHistoryRequest


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")


api_id   = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']
username = config['Telegram']['username']
bot__token = config['Telegram']['bot_token']

client = TelegramClient( username, api_id, api_hash )
bot = TelegramClient( 'bot' , api_id , api_hash ).start( bot_token = bot__token )


current_action = ''

async def dump_all_messages(channel):
    offset_msg = 0 
    limit_msg = 100
    
    all_messages = []
    total_messages = 0
    total_count_limit = 2
    
    class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        
        def default(self, o):
            if isinstance(o, datetime):
                return o.isoformat()
            if isinstance(o, bytes):
                return list(o)
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
                
    while True:
        history = await client( GetHistoryRequest (
                peer=channel,
                offset_id=offset_msg,
                offset_date=None,
                add_offset=0,
                limit=limit_msg, 
                max_id=0, 
                min_id=0,
                hash=0
            )
        )
        if not history.messages:
            break
        messages = history.messages
        for message in messages:
            all_messages.append(message.to_dict())
        offset_msg = messages[len(messages) - 1].id
        total_messages = len(all_messages)
        if total_count_limit != 0 and total_messages >= total_count_limit:
            break
        
    with open('channel_messages.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        json.dump(all_messages, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, cls=DateTimeEncoder)



@bot.on( events.NewMessage )
async def list( event ):
    match current_action:
        case '/tracking':
            channel = await client.get_entity( event.message.message )
            await dump_all_messages( channel )
            raise events.StopPropagation


@bot.on( events.NewMessage( pattern = '/tracking' ) )
async def link(event):
    global current_action
    current_action = '/tracking'
    await event.respond('I\'m expecting a link')
    raise events.StopPropagation

client.start()
bot.run_until_disconnected( )
```

Why is this happening (or rather where may the problem be)?

Comment: You should add a ``print(all_messages)` right before your json.dump method call and copy the output into your question so we can see what is causing the problem

Comment: It looks like the `messages` attributes of your `history` object is not a list of plain fully retrieved text messages. Instead, it would probably be a list of asynchronous coroutines (i.e. functions) that can be called on-demand when the content of each message is expected (to avoid unnecessary network overload). Before dumping to json, you should call the coroutine function of each message to retrieve its actual content, and then json-dump the list of fully retrieved messages.